# Any neat solution for determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been struggling to find the solution of the following system, though I do not want to write everything explicitly. I know that there is some trick which might be useful, but I could not find it. Anyway, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Let 
$
A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{11} &  \cdots & a_{1n} \\
  a_{21} &  \cdots & a_{2n} \\
  \vdots  & \ddots  &  \vdots  \\
  a_{n1} &  \cdots & a_{nn}
 \end{pmatrix}
$ and 
$
X=
  \begin{pmatrix}
   x_{1}\\
   \vdots\\
   x_n
  \end{pmatrix} 
$ where $|A|\neq0$. Show that
$$
|A+XX^{\prime}|
=\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & -x_1 & \cdots & -x_{n}\\
x_{1} & a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x_n & a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{vmatrix}=|A|\cdot(1+X^{\prime}A^{-1}X)
 $$

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to note that for suitably dimensioned $A,B$, we have $\det (I +AB) = \det (I + BA)$.

Then $A + x x^T = A(I+ A^{-1} x x^T)$, and $\det (A + x x^T) = \det A \det (I+ (A^{-1} x) x^T) = \det A \det (I+ x^T (A^{-1} x))$. Since the latter quantity is a scalar, we have $\det (A + x x^T) = (\det A) (1+x^T A^{-1} x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion is wrong. The correct statement should be
$$
-\det\underbrace{\pmatrix{-1&x^T\\ x&A}}_B = \det(A+xx^T) = \det(A)(1+x^TA^{-1}x).\tag{1}
$$
This is a direct application of [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). The Schur complement of $-1$ in $B$ is $A+xx^T$. Therefore
$$
\det(B)=(-1)\det(A+xx^T).\tag{2}
$$
Yet the Schur complement of $A$ in $B$ is $-1-x^TA^{-1}x$. So, we also have
$$
\det(B)=\det(A)(-1-x^TA^{-1}x).\tag{3}
$$
Equate $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get $(1)$.